# How to convert Epplus cell size to inches?

Tags: c#, spreadsheet, epplus

Let say I have a standard paper 'Letter' (8.5x11in).
The objective is to compute how many rows or columns would fit on the paper.
I used the factor of 1/72 for row height and 1/12 for column width to convert to inches.
The result is very close but not exact.
What is the relation between Epplus cell size and actual paper sizes in inches/ mm?

Comment: Any margins? And aren’t the cell dimensions adjustable?

Comment: @SolarMike, the cells dimensions are adjustable like every spreadsheet. There are ofcourse margins,but that may vary according to the user's preference.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to your question?